# SQL ERROR in Syntax when using WITH

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I want to use a SQL Query with the WITH clause an I get a Syntax Error.

I´m using MySQL Version 5.6.28

Here a simple Code example

```
WITH alias_test AS (SELECT id, title FROM `tips_locations`)
SELECT id, title
FROM alias_test
```

Here the error I get in my SQL Tool

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'alias_test AS (SELECT id, title FROM `tips_locations`) SELECT
>   id, title FROM ali' at line 1

Can you Help me?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support CTEs

Comment: mysql doesn't do it... I'd advise getting a refund.

Comment: WITH is now supported in MySQL 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support `WITH` clause or `CTE` and thus the error. Alternative, you can either use a temporary table or a normal table like

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE alias_test AS 
SELECT id, title FROM `tips_locations`;

SELECT id, title
FROM alias_test;
```